# TorrentTrader TorrentTrader v2.x Announce

Tags: php

```
$site_config["MEMBERSONLY"];{// local torrent so add passkey
    $dict = BDecode(file_get_contents($fn));
    $dict['announce'] = sprintf($site_config["PASSKEYURL2"],$CURUSER["passkey"]);



    unset($dict['announce-list']);


    $data = BEncode($dict);

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');

    //header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)); 

    header("Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent");

    print $data; 
    }
```

Ok here's the download.php file in these file is added passkey and url ... now the question is how to add 2nd announce in client ... second www.test.com/announce.php?somekey...

thanks for your answer !

Comment: What? Could you clarify your question? - Also perhaps change your title to a more relevant one?

Comment: ok i would like to add multiple announces into client (Bittorrent); you know now i got only one announce $siteconfig passkeyurl2 and a passkey now i would like to do is to add www.test.com/announce?passkey

Comment: and above is the code if i change  $dict['announce'] = sprintf($site_config["PASSKEYURL2"],$CURUSER["passkey"]);
these to spritf(www.somesite.com/announce.php) the torrent client will have these tracker in it but the question is how to add multiple trackers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$site_config["MEMBERSONLY"];{// local torrent so add passkey

    $dict = bdec_file($fn, filesize($fn));
$dict['value']['announce']['value'] = "http://test.com/announce.php?passkey={$CURUSER['passkey']}";
$dict['value']['announce']['string'] = strlen($dict['value']['announce']['value']).":".$dict['value']['announce']['value'];
$dict['value']['announce']['strlen'] = strlen($dict['value']['announce']['string']);



$announce_list = array( 
           array(
                 'value' => $dict['value']['announce']['value'],
           'type' => 'string')
         );
$announce_list2 = array(    
           array(
              'value' => 'http://whatever.com/passkey',
              'type' => 'string')
         );
$announce_list3 = array(    
           array(
              'value' => 'udp://open.demonii.com:1337/announce',
              'type' => 'string')
         );
#two trackers
$dict['value']['announce-list']['value'] = array( array( 'value' => $announce_list, 'type' => 'list' ),array( 'value' => $announce_list2, 'type' => 'list' ),array( 'value' => $announce_list3, 'type' => 'list' ));
#one tracker
#$dict['value']['announce-list']['value'] = array( array( 'value' => $announce_list, 'type' => 'list' ));
$dict['value']['announce-list']['type'] = 'list';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$row['filename'].'"');
header("Content-Type: application/x-bittorrent");
print(benc($dict));
}
?>
```

So i answer it myself and it works ... if anybody need it just copy and paste it